# How to enable browser caching for the images from Azure Blob Containers

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

How to enable browser caching for the images requested from Azure Blob Containers? Is there any way to define a max-age for the entire container?

Comment: try this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25528.azure-blob-storage-and-effective-use-of-cache-control-property.aspx